# EmptyStackException at java

Tags: java

**while i am running the below source  code**

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Assignment3 {

boolean conflict, complete = false;

public static int solve(int n) {

    int solution = 0;
    int nextQueen = 0;
    boolean problem = false;
    s.push(0);
    do{
      for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
      {
        if(s.get(i) == nextQueen){ 
          problem = true;
          break;
        }
        else if(s.get(i) - i == nextQueen - s.size()){
          problem = true;
          break;
        }
        else if(s.get(i) + i == nextQueen + s.size()){
          problem = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(problem = false){
        s.push(nextQueen);
        nextQueen = 0;}
      else{
        nextQueen++;
      }
      if(nextQueen == n){
        if(s.peek() == n){
          s.pop(); 
          nextQueen = s.pop()+ 1; 
        }
        else{
          nextQueen = s.pop()+ 1;
        }
      }
      }while(s.size() != n);

      printSolution(s);
      solution++;
      return solution;
      }


    private static void printSolution(Stack<Integer> s) {
      for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.size(); j ++) {
          if (j == s.get(i))
            System.out.print("Q ");
          else
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();  
    }

    // ----- the main method -----
    // (you shouldn't need to change this method)
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int n = 8;

      // pass in parameter n from command line
      if (args.length == 1) {
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim());
        if (n < 1) {
          System.out.println("Incorrect parameter");
          System.exit(-1);
        }//if   
      }//if

      int number = solve(n);
      System.out.println("There are " + number + " solutions to the " + n + "-queens problem.");
    }
}
```

**Getting the following error. Help me to clear :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
        at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:79)
        at Assignment3.solve(Assignment3.java:40)
        at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:87)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Well, `problem = false` is just wrong, but that's not really what's breaking you.  It's still worth fixing (and should be simplified to `!problem`).

Comment: Your `Stack` is empty at the time you are calling `[peek()]`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek())

Comment: Did you try running your code through a debugger. That would probably have shown you what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 4):

As per the API documentation, [`peek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek%28%29) method will throw `EmptyStackException`, if the stack is empty.

You have to check whether the stack is empty or not before peek a value from it. There is a [`empty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#empty%28%29) method which return a boolean depends on the stack

> Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as
>   the value of this function.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> The object at the top of this stack (the last item of the `Vector`
>   object).
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `EmptyStackException` - if this stack is empty.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause could be that there is an if condition saying `if(problem = false){` (actually it should be `problem==false` or even better `!problem`). The output of the statement `problem = false` will always be `false` hence the condition fails every time and nothing is added to the `Stack` (except for `s.push(0)` in the beginning). Now you are trying to pull (`peek()`) something from the `Stack` and the `Stack` is empty so you are getting the exception. Also it is best practice to always check if the stack is empty before pulling something from it. You can use `Stack.isEmpty()` for that purpose. I have not tested, but `problem = false` is definitely wrong.